# How I can create an UI like this with Flutter? Please help me

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Oi5.png)

How I can create an UI like this with Flutter? Please help me

Comment: You need to make an ui or integrate an notification service?

Comment: Just UI bro..can you give me suggestion pls

Comment: look into these widgets: Stack, Transform.scale, Transform.translate and Positioned

Comment: I can not make an UI with two border on the bottom like that. Can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: Try this package [flutter Stack card](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stack_card)